# Node , TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect'). error during mongoClient connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typeerror, undefined

[image]

How to resolve this error??? during mongodb connection?

```
const mongoClient=require('mongodb').mongoClient  
const state={
db:null
}
module.exports.connect=function(done){
const url='mongodb://localhost:27017'
const dbname='shopping'

mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
    if(err) return done(err)
    state.db=data.db(dbname)

    done()
})

}

module.exports.get=function(){
return state.db
}
```

Comment: Firstly, the [docs say](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mongodb-with-nodejs) it should be `MongoClient` not `mongoClient`. Secondly, it looks like `MongoClient` needs to be instantiated with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

First, change connection.js to the following:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

let dbConnection;
module.exports = {
  connectToDb: (cb) => {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/bookstore")
      .then((client) => {
        dbConnection = client.db();
        return cb();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return cb(err);
      });
  },
  getDb: () => dbConnection,
};
```

After that, you should require them in the app.js file:

```
const {connectToDb, getDb} = require('./config/connection')
```

Then, connect to the database:

```
let db;
connectToDb((err) => {
    if(!err){
       console.log('app is listening')
       db=getDb()
    }
})
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **mongoClient** with **MongoClient** and **MongoClient.connect()** with **MongoClient()**:

```js
const {MongoClient} = require("mongodb");

const connectToDb = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    const db = conn.db('<db_name>');
    console.log("Connected to Db");
    return {conn, db};
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error connecting to db', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

module.exports = connectToDb;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not `mongoClient`, replace it with `MongoClient`. The reason for the error is that it's case sensitive:

```
const MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient
```

Also replace `MongoClient.connect`